# Entity cannot be tracked because another instance is with the same key value

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to refresh the user achievements and when I try to refresh more than one this happen:

The instance of entity type 'UsersAchievements' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdUser'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, e
nsure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

```
public void RefreshUserAchiev(int id)
        {
            var userStats = _context.Stats.Find(id);

            var scoreAchievQuery = _context.Achievement.Where(s => s.Type == AchievementType.Score).ToArray();  
            var killsAchievQuery = _context.Achievement.Where(k => k.Type == AchievementType.Kills).ToArray();
            var roundsAchievQuery = _context.Achievement.Where(r => r.Type == AchievementType.Rounds).ToArray();
            
            foreach(Achievement scoreAchiev in scoreAchievQuery)
            {
                if (scoreAchiev.Value <= userStats.BestScore)
                {
                    UsersAchievements newUserAchiev = new UsersAchievements
                    {
                        IdUser = userStats.Id,
                        IdAchievement = scoreAchiev.IdAchievement
                    };

                    if (!_context.UsersAchievements.Where(a => a.IdUser == newUserAchiev.IdUser && a.IdAchievement == newUserAchiev.IdAchievement).Any())
                    {
                        _context.UsersAchievements.Add(newUserAchiev);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }
```

**DataContext**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbShooterland"));
        }

        public DbSet<Entity.User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Entity.Achievement> Achievement { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Entity.Stats> Stats { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Entity.UsersAchievements> UsersAchievements { get; set; }

    }
```

**Users Achievements Model**

```
public class UsersAchievements
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        
        public int IdAchievement { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but you should get all your Achievements from the dbContext in an only variable var achievements = _context.Achievement.ToList() and then to work with the achivements object instead of using _context.Achievement several times.
Could you try this to check id it solve your problem ?

Comment: You are potentially adding multiple `UsersAchievements` entities with the same key in that loop. The condition where you check whether a `UsersAchievements` with the same key already exists only evaluates to true if `IdAchievement == newUserAchiev.IdAchievement`, which is -- granted, without knowing your data -- unlikely as you're in a loop.

Comment: I resolve the problem by saying that IdAchievement is Key and it can be